# Jenkins scm user<->mail mapping. How to dump / restore / edit via cli

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

When setting up a new Hudson/Jenkins instance i run into the problem that i have to manually provide all the email addresses for the scm users.

We are using subversion and i can't generate the mail addresses from the usernames. I got a mapping but i found no way to copy / edit that without making use of the gui. With 20+ users that gets boring and i'd like to have just edit a file or something.

Maybe i'm missing some trivial thing like a scmusers.xml (which totally would do the job) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got 2 solutions so far:

- The users are stored in `users/USERNAME/config.xml` could be versioned / updated / etc.
- Makeing use of the [`RegEx+Email+Plugin`](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/RegEx+Email+Plugin), create one rule per user and version that file.

Comment: I can't find the file you mentioned in the first list item. The plugin looks promising. I am comparing this against CC.Net's `<email ...> (...) <converters> <regexConverter find="$" replace="@example.com" /> </converters> </email>`.

Answer (score 1):

With 20+ users, setting up a list for the scm users is the way to go.  Then when folks add/leave the group, you only have to edit the mailing list instead of the Hudson jobs.  Also depending on your mailing list software, folks might be able to add and drop themselves from the list which would save you the time of maintaining it yourself in Hudson.

You might also want to look into the alias support of whatever email server your Hudson server is using. Let Hudson send out the emails it wants to using the SVN usernames, but then define aliases in your /etc/aliases file (or equivalent for your email server) that map the SVN usernames to the actual email addresses.

Comment: I don't want hudson to mail everyone if a build breaks, that is going to happen 2-5 times a day and i don't want to have to "care" about those mails if the didn't commit since the last stable build :)